# Removing content controls from Docx

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I want to replace content controls(drop down list only) in a `docx` with actual text and then applying some logic on document to extract out tables using `apache-poi`. If I don't do it then cells having content control are not extracted.
If, I save my `docx` manually as Word 97-2003(`*.doc`) then it asks to removes all content controls and replace it with text being selected so I am planning to convert `docx` to `doc` to get rid of content controls.
I've explored so far:

- I came across `Aspose.words` library but it is paid one and can do a
  job in just 3 lines of code(tested with trial version).
- I tried `POI` itself but did not understand how to do it exactly. I tried below code:

  ```
   XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("<DOCX_FILE_PATH>"));`
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("<PATH_FOR_DOC_FILE>");
   doc.write(fos);
   fos.close();
  ```

It does create doc file but did not remove content controls as it did with `aspose`.

- I am restraining for now to try `JODConverter` because it relies on `LibreOffice` or `OpenOffice`- We don't have it on server and don't have permission to install new softwares.
- I looked into `Docx4J` but looks like it can't do it after checking its API.

what would be a best way to handle this scenario, is there any way to replace content controls directly? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please help me out in pointing what I missed? I did explore it but did not understand.

Comment: Updated question, thanks. I will be more clear in future and explore resources properly before coming here.

Comment: Updated subject now :)

Comment: docx4j can remove content controls (this is trivial: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlRemove.java ).  It can also bind content controls to an XML data part (more interesting).  Is your drop down list bound to an XML part?  Perhaps you could add the XML representing the content control to your question.

Comment: Converting to legacy binary .doc just to get rid of content controls seems like an odd solution.

Comment: @JasonPlutext That github solution worked perfectly - It replaced content control with static content. And, yes. drop down list bounds to an XML part. Thanks Sir.

Comment: If it is bound to an XML part, be aware that you might need to apply the bindings so that the content is up to date before removing the content controls!

Comment: Sure, I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docx4j can remove content controls

The essence of the sample code at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlRemove.java reproduced below:

```
    String input_DOCX = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/some.docx";

    // resulting docx
    String OUTPUT_DOCX = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/OUT_ContentControlRemove.docx";

    // Load input_template.docx
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));

    // There is no xml stream
    FileInputStream xmlStream = null;

    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);

    //Save the document 
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(OUTPUT_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
```